# Evaluating $b=1+2^\sqrt{\log_23}-3^\sqrt{\log_23}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Evaluating $b=1+2^\sqrt{\log_23}-3^\sqrt{\log_23}$

I am aware that $a^{\log_ax}=x$ but that doesn't seem to apply here.

$b=1+e^{\ln 2^\sqrt{\log_23}}-e^{\ln3^\sqrt{\log_23}}=1+e^{\sqrt{\frac{\ln3}{\ln2}}\ln2}-e^{\sqrt{\frac{\ln3}{\ln2}}\ln3}$

Not able to proceed next.

Comment: I am ready to bet that the problem is in fact $b=1+2^\sqrt{\log_23}-3^\sqrt{\log_32}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have posted the problem verbatim. But I think your guess is good. That matches with the given answer. So, thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we accept variant suggested by @Claude Leibovici, then we have
$$2^{\sqrt{\log_{2}{3}}}=\left(2^{\log_{2}{3}}\right)^\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log_{2}{3}}}=\\
3^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log_{2}{3}}}} = 3^{\sqrt{\log_{3}{2}}}$$
so
$$1+2^\sqrt{\log_23}-3^\sqrt{\log_32}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

I also assume the expression is $b=1+2^\sqrt{\log_23}-3^\sqrt{\log_32}$.
By the substitution , $\log_23=t\Rightarrow 3=2^t$ we have,

$$b=1+2^{\sqrt t}-(2^t)^{\sqrt{\tfrac1t}}=1$$